# struct keyword in gcc vs Borland C

Tags: gcc, struct

I'm confused about the struct definitions below. Shouldn't be both correct? With Borland C both compile, but with gcc only the second one compiles. The error is "unknown type name `_Node`".

```
typedef struct _Node {
    int item;
    _Node* next;
} Node;


typedef struct _Node {
    int item;
    struct _Node* next;
} Node;
```

Comment: Well probably BORLANDC falsely assumes C++ -like semantics (where a struct definition implies a typedef, such that  the struct keyword is not needed)

Comment: gcc is right in giving error as the struct variables must have the `struct` keyword (unless you have typedef'ed before the definition). Borland compiler has many bugs and doesn't comform to  C standard in many cases.

Comment: You are right. My mistake was that when I coded in BORLANDC I used a CPP file (by default when opening BORLANDC). It was very confusing. Thank you for the replay!

Comment: Identifiers starting with an underscore are reserved; you shouldn't use them in your own code. There is no need to use different identifiers for a struct tag and typedef; this: `typedef struct Node { int item; struct Node *next; } Node;` is perfectly legal, and lets you refer to the type either as `Node` or as `struct Node`. (Personally, I prefer to omit the typedef and refer to the type as `struct Node.)`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the compiler handles forward references. The gcc compiler may do,this by default since it is also a C++ compiler.

Comment: gcc acts as a C compiler *or* as a C++ compiler depending on the name of the source file (`.c` is C, `.cpp` and a few others are C++).

Answer (score 0):

No, in C only the second (explicitly including the `struct` specifier) is correct. While C++ allows the omission of `struct`, c does not, so this is a non-portable Borland extension. If you compile with g++, I imagine it should accept the first syntax as well.